# List items moved up on IE and Chrome for no apparent reason

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

basically I have this navigation menu, made with a list. Runs perfectly on Firefox but in Chrome and IE it's only working on the first page, all the others show like in this fiddle here (yeah it's not working on fiddle aswell).

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a id='0'>Entry0</a></li>
    <li><a id='1'>Entry1</a></li>
    <li><a id='2'>Entry2</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
#nav {
background-color:#31353e;
width:100%;
border-bottom:5px solid #d9d9d9;
height:55px;
}   
#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
#nav ul li a {
color:white;
font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-style:normal;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:300;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration:none;
padding:18px 20px 18px 20px;
border-bottom:5px solid #d9d9d9;
}
#nav ul li {
float:left;
margin-top:16px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
cursor:pointer;
border-bottom:5px solid #fafafa;
-webkit-transition:border-bottom-color 0.3s ease-in;
-moz-transition:border-bottom-color 0.3s ease-in;
transition:border-bottom-color 0.3s ease-in;
}
/* active item */
body#0 a#0, body#1 a#1, body#2 a#2, body#3 a#3 {
border-bottom:5px solid #fafafa;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blackice856/7p2p29mj/12/

Comment: can you point on a screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: just increase the li margin-top to 19px, that is what Im looking for, and works fine with 16px on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, looks like the problem was an 'em' tag in the html code. My editor automatically added it, it is solved now.